# double curly braces in quote mark - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Could some one tell me the full picture of the use of the quote mark and the double curly braces?

```
<a href="{{ url_for('delete_event', id=event.id) }}" class="text-danger">
```

The full code is as below.  Is it Django synatx `{{ ... }}` embeded?

```
{% for event in events %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ event.event }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.start_time }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.end_time }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.position }}</td>
              <td><a href="{{ url_for('delete_event', id=event.id) }}" class="text-danger">Delete</a></td>
              
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct url in template like this django does not support jinja tag, but django have a built in template language is called DTL (Django Template Language) so you need to correct in your code url pattern like this

```
{% for event in events %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ event.event }}</td>
    <td>{{ event.start_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ event.end_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ event.position }}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'delete_event' event.id %}" class="text-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```